# Changing commiter names in svn rep dump

Tags: svn

I want to change the commiters name in svn dump file. Is there any script to handle this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the svndumptool.

```
svnadmin dump path/to/my/repo > repo.dump

svndumptool transform-revprop svn:author originalregexp newvalue repo.dump newrepo.dump
```

This scripts may do the trick for you:

Check this out: http://justatheory.com/computers/vcs/svn/modify_author.html